# Open volumetric time series data set

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, computer-science, data-analysis, visualization

Does anyone know where I can find a good open volumetric time series data set?

I had a look at some of Stanford's open data sets (https://graphics.stanford.edu/data/voldata/ )

But these do not seem to be time series.

It would be useful to have a data set like this to test some mathematics in a program I am writing. Perhaps a 3D fluid flow data set is openly available somewhere?